# How to detect bluetooth message to remote device failed

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can we detect if data was sent successfully to remote bluetooth device? First approach is that remove device returns some message back e.g. ping-pong. Also I can put timer before `OutputStream.write` method and if it passes more than 1 minute and remote device didn't answer, we can conclude that the message wasn't sent to remove device. The same approach probably applies to wireless communication IEEE 802.11, ...  Is there anything else, have I missed something.

What about bluetooth devices like printers, headsets, ... do all return some message back when you send them command `write("commandName")`. Of course each device has its own API, but is there any general rule or document about bluetooth that states: for every command to the remote device, device will respond with "ok" message, so we know that message was received.

I have searched some APIs ([Android bluetooth](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte[]%29), tcp/ip C stack) and they all have the same signature for `write` method `void write(bytes)`. Can `write` method also be blocking? Or do we write new one e.g. `write(){ write_(); wait_for_response(); return; }`

Basically I'm asking about approach to send command to bluetooth device and how to detect if it was received successfully. What are some common approaches.

Answer (score 1):

You'll always need a response from the recipient, you should be sure that the message arrived. In addition, you can add data check: You create a packet sender calculates the checksum and sticks to the packet. The recipient receives the packet and calculates its own checksum and if it is same as sender checksum than  the data came all right.
Ways how to create a packet are more. Fixed-length packet data (e.g. 128byte) or floating-length packets of data and a special terminating character sequence. I come to combine the stop sequence with the number of bytes of data and checksum. Recipient buffer bytes, and when it finds a terminator sequence, than find the number of bytes of data and reads it from buffer and then he can calculates checksum.

example :

64 61 64 61 00 04 00 09 23 24 25

data0409#$%

#$% - Finishing sequence (fixed position in the packet)

09 - checksum (fixed position in the packet)

04 - Number of bytes of data (fixed position in the packet)

data - data (floating position a number of bytes)

**UPDATE**

It is important to keep in mind that the bytes do not go continuously, and the receiver in one "cycle of admission" can accept only part of the data package or many data packets at once. Therefore, it is necessary to use packet system and  received data save in buffer first and later came to check whether all the bytes of a packet arrived.

Comment: Agree on data checksum.